# Evaluating a vector that doesn't belong to a vector combination

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors

I am solving problems in : *Intorduction to Linear Algebra 4th ed.*

Problem 23, in Problem set 1 states:

> If you look at all combinations of those u, v, and w, is there any vector that can't be
> produced from eu + dv + ew? Different answer if u, v, ware all in __

given the vectors are:

[image]

I am new to linear Algebra, I don't understand which steps I should go through to evaluate that vector.

In 2D I would say it's a vector that belongs to a perpendicular plane, what is the case here?

Comment: It's a poorly written question, but the vector that goes from the tip of one vector to the tip of the another can be written as the difference of the two.

Comment: How can I rephrase it better?

Comment: I meant the problem in the book.